# MAPLE: How do I make this generation of a list of random matrices NOT include the word generate in front of each number?

Tags: matrices, maple, random-matrices

### my code in MAPLE says

`H:= Generate(list(RandomMatrix(7,3),4));`

which does generate four random matrices but before each number in each matrix
it says "Generate". 
How do I get rid of that?

Comment: This question is about programming and has nothing to do with math.  It should be closed or migrated.

Answer (score 0):

Generate in the RandomTools package.  Try something like

```
RandomTools:-Generate(list('Matrix'(rational(denominator=10),7,3),4));
```